# PyQt5 gui settings save

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt5

I have been making a GUI with pyQt5 and I'm at the point where I need to think about how to save the things the user do in my GUI. For example, if he/she checks a box I want it to be saved until next time they start the GUI.

I have been thinking of using a .ini file, but I'm asking if there is another file type I should be using or is there a function/class in pyQt5.

Sry for my bad English plus I'm on my phone typing.

Ty in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use QSettings, Its part of PyQt/Qt and handles location of your settings/config files.

https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtCore/QSettings.html

Comment: Please clarify your answer, as it's unclear if you're suggesting to use JSON/YAML/XML *or* QSettings. They all are valid formats, none of them excludes the others (theoretically), but you should make your answer more clear anyway, as right now it's not an actual answer and the proposed choices have no clear benefit or downside against each other.

Comment: Simplified and made concise my answer.